# Error loading python37 dll on Windows 7 after Pyinstaller created exe

Tags: python, dll, static, pyinstaller

I created an exe file using PyInstaller and it works on my PC with Windows 8.1 and laptop with Windows 10, but on computers with Windows 7 it has error

"error loading python37 dll "
and something about dynamic linked libraries.

EDIT:
Error loading Python DLL 'C:\Users\Dell\Appdata\Local|Temp|_MEI16442\python37.dll'. LoadLibrary: Procedure of initialize dynamic linked library (DLL) failed.
It is translated from Polish

Do you know maybe how can I fix it?
I was reading about static linked dll but I dont know how to do it. I am working on Windows only, I dont know Linux/Mac.

Comment: Post the full traceback. "something about dynamic linked libraries" is not helpful.

Comment: Does [this](http://pyinstaller.47505.x6.nabble.com/windows10-pyinstaller-can-t-find-python37-dll-td2454.html) help?

Comment: Error loading Python DLL
'C:\Users\Dell\Appdata\Local|Temp|_MEI16442\python37.dll'.
LoadLibrary: Procedure of initialize dynamic linked library (DLL) failed.

It is translated from Polish.

Comment: I was using .exe from dist directory. So its not the issue.

Comment: To run Python 3.7 on Windows 7 requires Windows Service Pack 1 and Update KB2533623. Does the target Windows 7 machine have these updates?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue while compiling the executable with a Pyinstaller command. To fix it, I added the `--noupx` option and everything worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

This used to happen to me all the time, and it was always because I tried to run the executable file from the **build** folder while the one that works is in the **dist** folder.

Comment: It is running from dist. So issue is in other thing :/